# Table row's border hidden in Firefox only

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox

I'm working on this website using Wordpress 
http://josedelavega.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/preise/

As you can see in this page there is a price table. For this table I'm using this Plug-in https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/table-maker/. On Google Chrome and Safari everything is ok, but if you check it on Firefox you cannot see the row's border.

Can I solve it via CSS?

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of how it’s supposed to look like?

Comment: Remove .`wpsm-comptable` class from table

Comment: Go to class  `.story table, .defaultwp table, .contentaboutbox table ` and remove property `border-collapse:collapse` , **In file general.css - line 368**, it will solve your issue.

Comment: This is a known Firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=688556

Comment: @AvAvt - Yes Agree :)

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my question's comment, this is a known Firefox bug. I can think of a way to solve this though, using background-clip. In your (plugin) css there should be this part:

```
.wpsm-comptable td {
    -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
    -moz-border-right-colors: none;
    -moz-border-top-colors: none;
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-color: #e8e8e8;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    color: #111;
    min-width: 120px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Try adding `background-clip: padding-box` to this selector. This should solve the issue.

Comment: It works :) thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions for the question:

1. Removed `border-collapse:collapse` from `.story table, .defaultwp table, .contentaboutbox table`

If you still want to keep border-collapse, then other option will be:

2. Add `background-clip: padding-box` to your td element. So add

   `.defaultwp table, .contentaboutbox table td {background-clip: padding-box}`

Check this for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-clip

3. Add position static to td

   `.defaultwp table, .contentaboutbox table td {position: static}`

But if you use pseudo-elements like ::before or ::after on the same td, position: static messes these stylings up. background-clip: padding-box is safer